# Как правильно преобразовать класс list в str с удалением лишних данных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, list, список

Есть данные в списке. Подскажите, как правильно преобразовать их в строку и удалить лишние данные?

Пример исходных данных:

```
[('simple musical instrument', 9.0), ('make', 1.0)]
    
<class 'list'>
```

требуется:

```
simple musical instrument 

<class 'str'>
```

Нужно вывести только ключевые слова с весом больше 1.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Answer (score 2):

```
words_list = [
    ('noise', 0.9), 
    ('simple', 7.3), 
    ('musical', 8.1), 
    ('drum', 1.0), 
    ('make', 1.0), 
    ('instrument', 3.3),
]

>>>type(words_list)
<class 'list'>
```

Обходите список кортежей, проверяйте значение второго элемента и соедините в строку с разделителем пробелом:

```
search_str = ' '.join(word[0] for word in words_list if word[1]>1)

>>> search_str
'simple musical instrument'

>>> type(search_str)
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Что такое "лишние данные" можно только догадываться. Но если догадки правильны, то например, так:

```
lt=[('simple musical instrument', 9.0), ('make', 1.0)]
st=[]
for row in lt:
    st.append(row[0])
st=' '.join(st)
print(st)
```

Или так:

```
st=str()
for row in lt:
    st=st+' '+row[0]
print(st)
```

Результат в обоих случаях тождественен:

```
simple musical instrument make
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я уточнил вопрос, нужно оставить только ключевые слова с весом больше 1 (для формирования поискового запроса)

Comment: @user446085 а если таких слов в списке несколько?